# Add another item - Update existing item

Tags: forms

I'm creating a form which will allows users to filter job applications using screening questions.  The user will be able to add up to 5 yes/no questions. The issue I'm having is deciding what most appropriate behaviour should be when a user wants to edit an existing question.

This is what the user will see if they add 3 questions.

[image]

If the user wants to edit question 2, the view changes to this:

[image]

Whilst in edit mode, I've decided to disable the other options (edit, add new) to prevent the user from clicking elsewhere. To exit this state, the user will have to click on cancel. Although, this will allow me to skip building a mechanism to hold half edited questions in a temporary state, it feels like a bit restrictive. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question.

The first image showing the list of 3 question is pretty straight forward and well structured. I would suggest to keep it.

1. When you are in edit mode to it the current solustions seems fair enough. Good to have avoided solutions like pop ups for edit mode.
2. Understanding the behavior of your user, since you have placed an explicit button for edit mode user edits only if user wants to(User Goal is specific and defined). User would not accidentally edit and during editing of question it is right to implement disabled functionality for other questions becuase now there are chances of user clicking elsewhere and the edit is lost that tends to rework.

However, you can edit the current design with one thing.
When you are in edit mode, the question you are editing currently is kept outside just about your edit card. If you dont show it outside explicilty(doesnt seem like it is under edit) you could give it a more user engagement experience.

In a nutshell, it is not a restriction you are imposing but a foolproof layout and solution.